# HTML5 Phonegap Mobile app slows down over time?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, cordova

I'm having a rather complicated problem.

I've built an HTML 5 app that uses socket.io to pull numbers from a server. Those numbers are then used in HTML5 canvas animations.

I have a pull-down refresh that pulls the numbers again and re-animates the canvases.

The problem is this, the animations (including the pull down refresh animations) slow dramatically over time on the ios simulator.

In other words, the app initially loads perfectly, and the animations for everything work find for a couple of seconds. After a few seconds, the animations become slower and slower until the simulator all but freezes.

Does anyone know why this is happening? I thought it could be a javascript loop but I don't really have any? Is this strictly a simulator problem?

Comment: You should share some code so we can see what you try to do. The typical reason is to not using `beginPath` but without seing any code we can't tell for sure...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on you code, but probably it should be  a simulator issue.. do you use a specific JS framework like jQuery or Bootstrap?

Check some recommendations to use jQuery + PhoneGap..

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/fine-tuning-jquery-mobile-phonegap-app

Comment: I think I may actually be on to something. I've been using setinterval in my code, but I think requestanimationframe will solve my problem.

Comment: @amilkcar please copy the relevant recommendation to your answer, in case jquery loses their forums like they did with their plugins.